# Linux - Debian 8 - Suspend Computer but never spin down HDD

Tags: debian, hard-disk, suspend

I am running a homeserver with several services using Debian and in order to save energy and to reduce the noise I am suspending the computer when I don't need any services.

To enhance the lifetime of the HDDs: 
Is there any way to force the HDD not to spin down but to suspend everything else?

I am using the command pm-suspend.

Answer (score 0):

Not without making hardware modifications, during standby and suspend the power-supply to the drives, and most of the other parts of the computer is turned off. only standby power is available. which is about 2.5W